# R Unused arguments in lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I am trying to run the following command:

```
sdi_sum <- sdi[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = c("location_id", "year_id", "sex_id"), .SDcols = c("sdi_value")]
```

The data table in question is something similar to this:

```
  location_id year_id    sdi_value age_group_id sex_id age_group_weight_value
1           6    1990 0.0001860878            2      1            0.000408021
2           6    1991 0.0001911983            2      1            0.000408021
3           6    1992 0.0001954346            2      1            0.000408021
4           6    1993 0.0001993269            2      1            0.000408021
5           6    1994 0.0002031715            2      1            0.000408021
6           6    1995 0.0002080753            2      1            0.000408021
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(sdi, , lapply(.SD, sum), by = c("location_id",  : 
  unused arguments (by = c("location_id", "year_id", "sex_id"), .SDcols = c("sdi_value"))
```

The same line of code works with a different data frame, that contains the same "by" grouping.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: first of all you only have one column under .SDcols, you do not need `lapply`. Try `sdi[, sum(sdi_value), by = c("location_id", "year_id", "sex_id")]`

Comment: The lapply works with a singular column as I tried with another dataset just now. I did also try  sdi[, sum(sdi_value), by = c("location_id", "year_id", "sex_id")] , but ended up with the same error message.

Comment: seems you are working on a dataframe instead of a data.table. just do `library(data.table);setDT(sdi)` and then run your code

Answer (score 0):

The `by` is only available in `data.table` and not in a dataframe. Convert your data to a data.table as below:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(sdi)
```

Now run your code